# Speech recognition library for a specific task

Tags: speech-recognition

I want to extract all usages (with some margin of error) of a particular phrase from a set of audio files with total length of approximately 30 hours. I have no experience with speech recognition software, where should I start looking? Language/platform doesn't really matter.

More details. What I want to do is to find all usages of a catchphrase in all episodes of a TV show. So, it doesn't have to be done in realtime and language model probably won't help here.

Comment: There is nothing specific in this task, you can use any speech recognition engine for that, you just need to open google and search or "speech recognition engine"

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I've provided some details.

Comment: You basically repeated the same thing in a different words. Instead you could do your own research and ask more specific question.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Elitist Russian programmer strikes again. As I've indicated, I have no experience with speech recognition so I don't even know where to start. Should I read some books (which ones?), research papers (which ones?) or a documentation for some library (which one?)

Comment: Also asked here: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9493/speech-recognition-library-for-detecting-phrase-in-file